# How do I import a model in a XCTest for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I am attempted to build my first non tutorial app in swift and having trobule with testing.

I have created a User : NSObject

```
//
//  User.swift

import UIKit

public class User: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage?

    init(name: String, image: UIImage?) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

And put a test together based on the [Apple Swift testing Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH20-SW1)

```
//
//  LocalTalkTests.swift

import UIKit
import XCTest

class LocalTalkTests: XCTestCase {
//   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH20-SW1 

    func testUserInitialization() {
        let potentialUser = User(name: "Newest meal", image:nil)
        XCTAssertNotNil(potentialUser, "User can't be nil" )
    }

}
```

I don't understand how the User object gets known in the test. I have used Objective-C on a previous project and just used the #`import "file.h` keyword.

How do I make sure I can user this object in the test, or at least make it public facing?

*I am using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6

Comment: Hit the target membership checkbox on the file you want to include with your test target (and you are done)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I found this blog post helpfu as welll http://natashatherobot.com/swift-unit-testing-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was add my project to my test target.

I found these 2 blog post great explanations about that

http://natashatherobot.com/swift-unit-testing-tips-and-tricks/
http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/22/swift-access-control-implications-for-unit-testing/

as well as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661334/why-are-the-targets-memberships-checkboxes-disabled-for-all-files)